# same item value when accessed with getIntent() in other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, oncreate

My code flow is:

`Reports => ReportsType`

Reports is having 3 items and on click of each item, I am starting the activity `ReportsType` passing the tag with the name `name` in the intent to distinguish which item was clicked.

The problem is OnCreate method is called only once, so heading is always set to what item was clicked in the starting.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle si)
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        heading = intent.getExtras().getString("name"); //this tells which item was clicked.
        TextView heading_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading);
        heading_txt.setText(heading);
     }
```

I tried to put this code at `onResume()` call because it is called everytime the activity resumes. But still the `getIntent()` is giving the old `name` value set from previous item.

How to get the current clicked item intent value in the other activity?

UPDATE:

**Reports activity code:**

```
   public void showReport(View v) {
    String tag = v.getTag().toString();
    Intent i5 = new Intent(this, ReportsType.class);
    i5.putExtra("name", tag);
    startActivity(i5);

}
```

Where `showReport()` method is called each item you click any of the three items.

UPDATE:

**goBackReport code**

```
public void goBackReport(View v)
    {

    Intent intent = new Intent(ReportsType.this, Reports.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

**XML button view**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_xml"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:onClick="goBackReport"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Comment: Post your Reports Activity code too

Comment: I have understood your question, but I have a confustion regarding `problem is OnCreate method is called only once, so heading is always set to what item was clicked in the starting` are you  pressing back button?

Comment: Make sure that you pass correct View to ShowReport() and the tag is different for each views

Comment: @Pragnani correct I am pressing back button in `ReportsType` activity which again sends me to `Reports` activity. Then I click the next item but the value I get from tag is of the first item. Because `OnCreate()` method is called only for first item or only once.

Comment: When you click BACK in `ReportsType`, that activity will be finished and you will return to `Reports` activity. If you then call `startActivity()` to start `ReportsType` again, for sure `ReportsType.onCreate()` will be called. There is something else going on here. Add debug logging in `ReportsType.onCreate()` to see what it gets in the `Intent` and add debug logging in `showReport()` to see when it is called and what you are sending.

Comment: My `Reports` and `ReportsType` classes are not extending `Activity` but they are extending `FragmentActivity`. Is that something to do with that? Morever, my onBackPressed() is never getting called. So I am calling some method when click on back button which is directly defined in ReportsType xml. And in that method I called `finish()` which finishes all the fragmentActivities and I see the homescreen rather than `Reports` class view.

Comment: What method are you calling when the user clicks the BACK button in `ReportsType`? Why? Post the code of that method.

Comment: @Pragnani My back button is not calling `onBackPressed()`. I used your code in a method other than `onBackPressed()` and I am getting a slight delay on a call to `finish()` with a blank screen.

Comment: I am calling `goBackReport(View v)` method when the user clicks on back button because `onBackPressed()` is not getting called on back button click. In xml of button I defined - `android:onClick="goBackReport"`. See the code of the `goBackReport` in the question.

Comment: @SaurabhJain is your code working , as you haven't setContentView and you are trying to get the TextView, so you'll probably get `NPE`

Comment: @Pragnani But how the activity will know that its the back button clicked just by name. I mean there may be lots of buttons with different functionalities. How it will distinguish.

Comment: @Pragnani Ok see my button view in the question updated.

Comment: I have already set the `contentview` and that's why I am seeing my view of `ReportsType` class.

Comment: Why do you need a software BACK button? All devices have a hardware BACK button. If you really need a software BACK button, then `goBackReport()` should just call `finish()`. That's it.

Comment: @SaurabhJain So my answer doesn't provide answer to your question..So I am deleting it...

Comment: @DavidWasser It was just understanding problem...I really appreciate your support..

Comment: @DavidWasser If I call just `finish()` then it finishes all the `Reports` and `ReportsType` activity classes and I see the `MainFragmentActivity` class view.

Comment: Then I don't understand. When `Reports` starts `ReportsType` does it then call `finish()`? It shouldn't.

Comment: It doesn't call `finish()` as you see in the `showReport()` method. That's what I have to start `Reports` activity.

Comment: Still don't understand. Your `Reports` activity is running. It starts `RerportsType` activity and does NOT call `finish()` on itself. That means `Reports` activity is still in the activity stack in paused state. Now, when you call `finish()` in `ReportsType` activity, that will remove `ReportsActivity` from the activity stack and return to the activity underneath it, which should be `Reports` activity, where it will call `onResume()`. That's what should happen. You can verify what activities are in the activity stack by using `adb shell dumpsys activity` and look at the output.

Comment: You are still right. I have put a logger in `onResume()` method of `Reports` activity to verify that after a `finish()` call in `ReportsType` activity, where its going. Surprisingly, its going to `onResume()` method of `Reports` activity but after that what's causing a call to `MainFragmentActivity` is unknown. However if I start activity intent `Reports` and then call `finish()` as mentioned earlier then everything works fine except then I get a certain delay(a blank screen) and then the view `Reports` activity is shown just fine.

Comment: Moreover I ran `adb shell dumpsys activity` and got this output: `Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{41dd3920 #120 A com.wassap.main U 0}
    Run #8: ActivityRecord{4194e200 com.wassap.main/.ReportsType}
    Run #7: ActivityRecord{41aadf20 com.wassap.main/.Reports}
    Run #6: ActivityRecord{4165f998 com.wassap.main/.MainFragmentActivity}
    Run #5: ActivityRecord{41b8e060 com.wassap.main/.MainFragmentActivity}
    Run #4: ActivityRecord{41a93e80 com.wassap.main/.Reports}`

Comment: If you look at the activity stack from your recent comment, you can see that this is a mess. You have 2 instances of `Reports`, 2 instances of `MainFragmentActivity` and 1 instance of `ReportsType` in your activity stack. This is probably not what you want. You need to have a hard look at how your start your activities.

Comment: I resolved the issue. See my answer below. For the number of instances, I assume that some background process is going too creating multiple instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally resolved by setting the old intent value in the called activity like this-

```
@Override
    public void onNewIntent (Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }
```

Then getting the old intent values at `onResume()` call-

```
@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        heading = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
        TextView heading_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading);
        heading_txt.setText(heading);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like in your second `Activity`

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        String  mstr = getIntent().getExtras().getString("yourkey");               
        }
```

and your code

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        heading = intent.getExtras().getString("name"); //this tells which item was clicked.
        TextView heading_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading);
        heading_txt.setText(heading);
```

put in `onItemclick` where it need not in `onCreate`